# Is there a name for the pattern where you emergency break a possible infinite loop?

Tags: design-patterns, while-loop

I'm looking for some more info/inspiration and was wondering if there is a pattern for the following.

Now and then I have something that should not be an infinite loop, but CAN be an infinite loop if a bug is introduced.

As it is in a Web Application I rather have it to throw an exception if we more or less know it hangs instead of a thread getting stuck and slowly depleting all resources.

Some similar code below, it's not about the details.

Is there a name for this pattern or any other words for looking up more thoughts about this?

```
while ( _Combinations.Any() )
{
    var combination = _Combinations.First();

    combination.New.DuplicateIndex = combination.Current.DuplicateIndex;

    RemoveAllFromCombinations(combination.New);

    if ( emergency_break++ > 10_000 )
        throw new ArgumentException("More loops then expected - crash instead of hang");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would apply a template method pattern.

Here is a simple Java example:

```
public class LoopTemplate {

    private int maxIterations;

    public LoopTemplate(int maxIterations) {
        this.maxIterations = maxIterations;
    }

    public void execute(LoopCondition loopCondition, IterationCallback iterationCallback) {
        int iterationCount = 0;

        while (loopCondition.isFulFilled()) {
            iterationCallback.run(iterationCount++);

            if (iterationCount >= maxIterations) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Max iteration count exhausted");
            }
        }
    }
}

public interface LoopCondition {

    public boolean isFulFilled();
}

public interface IterationCallback {

    public void run(int iterationCount);
}
```

I can then use it in this way

```
LoopTemplate loopTemplate = new LoopTemplate(2);

loopTemplate.execute(() -> true, (int iterationCount) -> {
    System.out.println("iteration: " + iterationCount);
});
```

and the output would be:

```
iteration: 0
iteration: 1

java.lang.RuntimeException: Max iteration count exhausted
```

Depending on your needs you might want to implement a DSL so that it is more readable:

```
loopTemplate
   .until(() -> true)
   .run((int iterationCount) -> {
        System.out.println("iteration: " + iterationCount);
        }
    )
```

You also might want to add methods to the iteration callback in order to break and continue the loop.

```
public interface IterationCallback {
    public void run(Loop loop);
}

public interface Loop {
    public int iterationCount();
    public void breakLoop();
    public void nextIteration();
}
```

But the implementation will get a bit more tricky then.
You must decide if it is worth it.